# Calculating % of single row to sum of rows - Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to calculate the % contribution of the a's in the "qual" column to the total sales for each loc.

```
loc | qual | sales 
- - - - - - - - - - - - 
us  |  a   |  1,000 
us  |  b   |  500 
gc  |  a   |  200
gc  |  b   |  400
```

So the answer that I would be looking for is US = 66.66% (1,000/1,500) and gc = 33.33% (200/600). So the return result would be....

```
loc | Pct 
us  | 66.66%
gc  | 33.33%
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with aggregation and window functions:

```
select loc, count(*) as sales, sum(count(*)) over () as total_sales,
       count(*) / sum(1.0*count(*)) over () as sales_proportion
from t
group by loc;
```

If `sales` is really an integer, may should convert it to a floating point or decimal representation (you can just multiple by 1.0).

EDIT:

Oops, the above does something useful, but not what the OP asks for.  Here is the simplest method:

```
select loc,
       avg(case when qual = 'a' then 1.0 else 0 end) as proportion_a
from t
group by loc;
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually realized a mistake as I was using your solution. The "sales" column actually has transactionsIDs so I need to find the count of transactions for "a" over the total transactions in each loc. Is this possible to do with count?

Sorry in advance for the bad formatting!

select
loc,
count(transactionID) as Transactions, 
count(count(transactionID)) over () as TotalTransactions, count(transactionID)/ count(count(transactionID)) over () as total_proportion

from t

group by loc;

Comment: No . . . you want `sum(count(TransactionId))`.

Comment: @Bocean . . . In any case, I answered the wrong question.  See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need a *conditional aggregate*:

```
select loc, 
   100.00
     * sum(case when qual = 'a' then sales else 0 end) -- only 'a' sales 
     / sum(sales) as Pct                               -- all sales
from tab
group by loc
```

Change the precision of `100.00 *` according to your needs.

Caution, unless the datatype of `sales` is a FLOAT or NUMBER you must multiply `100 *` first and then divide.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the percentage, you know that you will need to sum over loc. But you don't want to group by loc and aggregate, because that will destroy parts of the table that you want to keep, and inner joining that resulting table back to the table you have here ... well, there's gotta be an easier way. And that's where a correlated subquery comes in! You can perform a subselect that counts the sales correlated to the loc in your table. The following code should give you what you want.

```
select  loc,
        sales * 100 / (
            select sum(sales)
            from my_table sq
            where sq.loc = t.loc
        ) as pct
    from my_table t
    where qual = 'a'
```

Hope this helps!